# Query for transitive word translation

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have trouble constructing what I guess should be a CTE query, which would return a word translation.

I have two tables - WORDS:

```
ID | WORD | LANG
1   'Cat'   'ENG'
2   'Kot'   'POL'
3   'Katze' 'GER'
```

and CONNECTIONS:

```
ID | WORD_A | WORD_B
1       1         2
2       1         3
```

As ENG->POL, and ENG->GER translations already exist, I would like to receive a POL->GER translation.

So for any given word, I have to check it's connected translations, if target language is not there, I should check connected translations of those connected translations etc., up to the point where either translation is found, or nothing is returned;

I have no idea where to start, it wouldn't be a problem if there was a constant number of transitions required, but it might as well require transition like POL->ITA->...->ENG->GER.

Comment: in connection table either it would be 1-3 or POL->GER  already exists???which one is it correct it??

Comment: This requires a recursive CTE.  What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: @nikhilsugandh there was an error in table, as mentioned POL<->ENG, and ENG<->GER connections exist only

Comment: @novarek that is what i said !!! i corrected it the second time!!!!!

Comment: @GordonLinoff version 3.23.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complicated graph walking problem.  The idea is to set up a `connections2` relationship that has words and languages in both directions, and then use this for walking the graph.

To get all German translations for Polish words, you can use:

```
with words AS (
      select 1 as id, 'Cat' as word, 'ENG' as lang union all
      select 2, 'Kot', 'POL' union all
      select 3, 'Katze', 'GER'
     ),
     connections as (
      select 1 as id, 1 as word_a, 2 as word_b union all
      select 2 as id, 1 as word_a, 3 as word_b
     ),
     connections2 as (
      select c.word_a as id_a, c.word_b as id_b, wa.lang as lang_a, wb.lang as lang_b
      from connections c join
           words wa
           on c.word_a = wa.id join
           words wb
           on c.word_b = wb.id
      union  -- remove duplicates
      select c.word_b, c.word_a, wb.lang as lang_a, wa.lang as lang_b
      from connections c join
           words wa
           on c.word_a = wa.id join
           words wb
           on c.word_b = wb.id
     ),
     cte as (
      select id as pol_word, id as other_word, 'POL' as other_lang, 1 as lev, ',POL,' as langs
      from words
      where lang = 'POL'
      union all
      select cte.pol_word, c2.id_b, c2.lang_b, lev + 1, langs || c2.lang_b || ','
      from cte join
           connections2 c2
           on cte.other_lang = c2.lang_a
      where langs not like '%,' || c2.lang_b || ',%' or c2.lang_b = 'GER'
     ) 
select *
from cte
where cte.other_lang = 'GER';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=7cc0f93ccc320d525e00275f3e7cbee0) is a db<>fiddle.

Presumably, you want the shortest path.  For that, you would use this query (after the CTEs):

```
select *
from cte
where cte.other_lang = 'GER' and
      cte.lev = (select min(cte2.lev) from cte cte2 where ct2.pol_word = cte.pol_word);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing your table design to something along these lines:

```
ID | WORD_ID | WORD    | LANG
1  | 1       | 'Cat'   | 'ENG'
2  | 1       | 'Kot'   | 'POL'
3  | 1       | 'Katze' | 'GER'
```

Now suppose that you want to go from Polish to German, and you are starting off with the Polish word for cat, `Kot`.  Then, you may use the following query:

```
SELECT t2.WORD
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.WORD_ID = t1.WORD_ID AND t2.LANG = 'GER'
WHERE
    t1.WORD = 'Kot' AND t1.LANG = 'POL'
```

### Demo

The idea here is that you want one of your tables to maintain a mapping of every logically distinct word to some common id or reference.  Then, you only need an incoming word and language, and a desired output language, to be able to do the mapping.

Note: For simplicity I am only showing a table with a single word across a handful of language, but the logic should still work with multiple words and languages.  Your current table may not be normalized, but optimizing that might be another task separate from your immediate question.

Comment: I had a similiar approach to begin with, but there is a small issue: I haven't got a limited set of languages, and translations are received from google api.

When user attempts to translate cat - 'Gatto' (ITA) to 'Neko' (JAP), two new translations appear, but how can I know to which WORD_ID should I add them to?

Comment: Are you saying that you are using the Google API, as an end-user, to populate your table?  Can you elaborate on what you are actually doing here?

Comment: A small, personal use project to learn Qt -  desktop google translate client, with caching functionality - I want previously requested translations to be stored, and same word in different languages to be connected.

Comment: But of course, if changing db schema is acceptable, then your solution is perfectly fine!